# logging problem with juju bootstrap

Tags: juju, maas

I have trouble with using juju and maas with Ubuntu.

I I ran command 'juju bootstrap', the following error was shown in /var/log/maas/maas.log:

====================================================================================
ERROR 2012-11-26 09:05:09,041 maas.maasserver ################################ Exception: File not found ################################

159 ERROR 2012-11-26 09:05:09,041 maas.maasserver Traceback (most recent call last):

160   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 111, in get_response

161     response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

162   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/decorators/vary.py", line 19, in inner_func

163     response = func(*args, **kwargs)

164   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/piston/resource.py", line 167, in **call**

165     result = self.error_handler(e, request, meth, em_format)

166   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/piston/resource.py", line 165, in **call**

167     result = meth(request, *args, **kwargs)

168   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/maasserver/api.py", line 296, in dispatch

169     return function(self, request, *args, **kwargs)

170   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/maasserver/api.py", line 945, in get_file

171 MAASAPINotFound: File not found

172

173 ERROR 2012-11-26 09:05:09,343 maas.maasserver ################################ 
Exception: You are not allowed to start up this node. #####    ###########################

174 ERROR 2012-11-26 09:05:09,343 maas.maasserver Traceback (most recent call last):

175   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 111, in get_response

176     response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

177   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/decorators/vary.py", line 19, in inner_func

178     response = func(*args, **kwargs)

179   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/piston/resource.py", line 167, in **call**

180     result = self.error_handler(e, request, meth, em_format)

181   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/piston/resource.py", line 165, in **call**

182     result = meth(request, *args, **kwargs)

183   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/maasserver/api.py", line 296, in dispatch

184     return function(self, request, *args, **kwargs)

185   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/maasserver/api.py", line 585, in start

186     "You are not allowed to start up this node.")

187 PermissionDenied: You are not allowed to start up this node.

====================================================================================

It seems that there is problem with getting a file in api.py.
So, I tried to add some logs like the following, but maasserver can not recognize 'logging' module.

```
import logging
...
logger = logging.getLogger('maas.maasserver')
logger.info(filename)
```

Could you let me know

1. how to add logs in juju and maasserver python scripts ?
2. how to debug maasserver and juju python script more easily ?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your API key is invalid.  You didn't say what versions of anything you're using, but go to your user page in MAAS and copy the API key into the juju environments.yaml again.

Comment: I forgot to say, ignore the "file not found", that's normal on first bootstrap.